# Why virtualbox fails to install on Ubuntu20.04

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtualbox-guest-additions, dkms, ubuntu-20.10

I am trying to install virtualbox. I had it installed previously and it worked. Today I tried to add another virtual machine and it started complaining about problems with dkms so I tried to purge and install everything with the following failure.

```
$  sudo apt install virtualbox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dkms libgsoap-2.8.91 libqt5opengl5 libsdl1.2debian libvncserver1 virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt
Suggested packages:
```

I could not submit my question without skipping some output

```
Building initial module for 5.8.0-36-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/virtualbox-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-dkms (--configure):
 installed virtualbox-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox:
 virtualbox depends on virtualbox-dkms (>= 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) | virtualbox-source (>= 6.1.10-dfsg-1~u
buntu1.20.04.1) | virtualbox-modules; however:
  Package virtualbox-dkms is not configured yet.
  Package virtualbox-source is not installed.
  Package virtualbox-modules is not installed.
  Package virtualbox-dkms which provides virtualbox-modules is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-qt:
 virtualbox-qt depends on virtualbox (= 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1); however:
  Package virtualbox is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-qt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                            No ap
port report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                       Processing
 triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.15-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-dkms
 virtualbox
 virtualbox-qt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

## dkms error

> $ cat /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/make.log  DKMS make.log
> for virtualbox-6.1.10 for kernel 5.8.0-36-generic (x86_64) Tue 12 Jan
> 12:40:32 GMT 2021 make: Entering directory
> '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-36-generic'   CC [M]
> /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o
> CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrv.o   CC
> [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvGip.o   CC
> [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvSem.o   CC
> [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvTracer.o   CC
> [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/SUPLibAll.o   CC
> [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/alloc-r0drv.o
> CC [M]
> /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/initterm-r0drv.o
> CC [M]
> /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/memobj-r0drv.o
> CC [M]
> /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/mpnotification-r0drv.o
> CC [M]
> /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/powernotification-r0drv.o
> CC [M]
> /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/assert-r0drv-linux.o
> In file included from ./include/asm-generic/percpu.h:7,
> from ./arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:556,
> from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
> from ./include/linux/preempt.h:78,
> from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:51,
> from /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/../SUPDrvInternal.h:79,
> from /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:32:
> /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c: In
> function ‘supdrvOSChangeCR4’:
> /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:760:38:
> error: ‘cpu_tlbstate’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you
> mean ‘cpuhp_state’?   760 |     RTCCUINTREG uOld =
> this_cpu_read(cpu_tlbstate.cr4);
> |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~ ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:318:9: note: in definition of macro
> ‘**pcpu_size_call_return’   318 |  typeof(variable) pscr_ret**;     
> |         ^~~~~~~~ /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:760:24:
> note: in expansion of macro ‘this_cpu_read’   760 |     RTCCUINTREG
> uOld = this_cpu_read(cpu_tlbstate.cr4);
> |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:760:38:
> note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each
> function it appears in   760 |     RTCCUINTREG uOld =
> this_cpu_read(cpu_tlbstate.cr4);
> |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~ ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:318:9: note: in definition of macro
> ‘**pcpu_size_call_return’   318 |  typeof(variable) pscr_ret**;     
> |         ^~~~~~~~ /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:760:24:
> note: in expansion of macro ‘this_cpu_read’   760 |     RTCCUINTREG
> uOld = this_cpu_read(cpu_tlbstate.cr4);
> |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:290:
> /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o]
> Error 1 make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs.... make[1]: ***
> [scripts/Makefile.build:519:
> /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv] Error 2 make: ***
> [Makefile:1780: /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build] Error 2 make:
> Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-36-generic'

Answer (score 13):

Had the same issue But finally got it fixed!!!

By removing Virtualbox completely and reinstalling it.

Tried downgarding the kernel but that did'nt work for me

```bash
sudo apt-get purge "^virtualbox-.*"

sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean
```

Then download the latest virtualbox version from this link for ubuntu 20.04

> https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

I tried many other solutions, none worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install virtualbox from its [download page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) to make sure that it's the latest version of virtualbox (6.1.16). 
 If it's still failing, maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65699337/14997224) can help

Comment: Sadly the answer you mentioned would not work until I downgraded the kernel. After downgrading the kernel simple 'sudo apt install virtualbox' has worked just fine.

Comment: same problem here. Thought this is a virtualbox bug

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue.
Steps that I followed:

- Completely uninstalled and purged the previously failed to install virtualbox files

> `sudo apt-get purge "^virtualbox-.*"`
>
> `sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean`

- Ran the installer for ["All Distributions"](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/7.0.6/VirtualBox-7.0.6-155176-Linux_amd64.run) by running wget

> `wget https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/7.0.6/VirtualBox-7.0.6-155176-Linux_amd64.run`

- Making the file executable

> `chmod +x ./VirtualBox-7.0.6-155176-Linux_amd64.run`

- Running installing script

> `sudo ./VirtualBox-7.0.6-155176-Linux_amd64.run`

*Note: You may need to change the version number for what*

Comment: Just used 
sudo apt-get purge "^virtualbox-.*"

and then follow the same steps you have followed and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Removing kernel versions like 5.8 and downgrading to 5.4.0-60-generic has solved the problem. After booting with kernel 5.4.0-60-generic I was able to install Virtualbox using synaptic and my new virtual machine works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, removing or downgrade your kernel and solved problem. You could use mainline and grub-cusomizer.

grub-cusomizer:https://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/03/11/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-18-04-lts/

mainline: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/08/mainline-install-latest-kernel-ubuntu-linux-mint/

Answer (score 0):

the easiest solution is to install libgsoap manually and then try installing VirtualBox, I did the same it worked for me

https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/libgsoap-2.8.91_2.8.91-2_amd64.deb.html

above is the link to install

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It's not recommended to install any software from Terminal because you always  will get the old version of that software .Hence,its always better to install and download software from their particular's  official website ..

In ur case,its better to exit the Terminal and try to install virtualbox from their respective official website:

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

If this also don't work then try to remove all the virtualbox dependencies from Synaptic Package Manager and again
install virtualbox ..